# "Sequence contains no matching element" i am getting this error while execute Linq code

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am getting "Sequence contains no matching element" when trying to compare and assign some data using LINQ query

```
cfgData.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().
  ForEach(row => row["Name"] =
            valData.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().
              First(x => Convert.ToInt32(row["AccountTypeId"]).
                           Equals(Convert.ToInt32(x["Id"])))["AccountType"]);
```

In context:

```
public static object DeployAccountTypes()
{
  using (SqlConnection cfgConn = Connection.GetConnection(NamedConnection.Configuration))
  using (SqlConnection valConn = Connection.GetConnection(NamedConnection.Validation))
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT *, '' as Name FROM tcRAPIDAccountTypes (NOLOCK) ORDER BY EvaluationOrder", cfgConn))
  using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tcRAPIDLoadAccountTypes (NOLOCK)", valConn))
  {
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable cfgData = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(cfgData);

    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataTable valData = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(valData);

    // ERROR HERE
    cfgData.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().
      ForEach(row => row["Name"] =
                valData.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().
                  First(x => Convert.ToInt32(row["AccountTypeId"]).
                               Equals(Convert.ToInt32(x["Id"])))["AccountType"]);
```

Data from `SELECT * FROM tcRAPIDLoadAccountTypes (NOLOCK)`:

```
Id  AccountType AccountTypeDescription  LOB
1   ABDNPROP    NULL                    AP
2   ASR         NULL                    CAS
4   BBUS        NULL                    CAS
5   BRETL       NULL                    CAS
6   BUSFLPOA    NULL                    CAS
7   BVICMN      NULL                    CAS
8   CORP        NULL                    CAS
9   CPSACCT     NULL                    CPS
10  DEFAULT     NULL                    CODG
```

Data from `SELECT *, '' as Name FROM MLSNAPS_XTCMConfig.dbo.tcRAPIDAccountTypes (NOLOCK) ORDER BY EvaluationOrder`:

```
Id  AccountTypeId   Description IsActive
6   45              NULL        1
7   46              NULL        1
8   16              NULL        1
9   23              NULL        1
10  22              NULL        1
11  49              NULL        1
12  20              NULL        1
13  18              NULL        1
14  17              NULL        1
15  15              NULL        1
```

Comment: Did you test if both cfgData and valData are not empty ?

Comment: yes , i have validate .

Comment: i found the root cause ie : data in Convert.ToInt32(row["AccountTypeId"] and Convert.ToInt32(x["Id"] are not same that's why i am facing this issuu.i was tried with  FirstOrDefault as well but it return null value (as expected ) and getting another error (Object not set to instance of an object)

Answer (score 0):

Try a join :

```
public static object DeployAccountTypes()
{
  using (SqlConnection cfgConn = Connection.GetConnection(NamedConnection.Configuration))
  using (SqlConnection valConn = Connection.GetConnection(NamedConnection.Validation))
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT *, '' as Name FROM tcRAPIDAccountTypes (NOLOCK) ORDER BY EvaluationOrder", cfgConn))
  using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tcRAPIDLoadAccountTypes (NOLOCK)", valConn))
  {
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable cfgData = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(cfgData);

    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataTable valData = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(valData);

    var results = (from cfg in cfgData.AsEnumerable()
        join val in valData.AsEnumerable() on cfg.Field<int>("AccountTypeId") equals val.Field<int>("Id")
        select new { cfg = cfg, val = val })
        .ToList();
  }

}
```

Comment: can you please modified  the code  " cfgData.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach(row => row["Name"] = valData.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().First(x => Convert.ToInt32(row["AccountTypeId"]).Equals(Convert.ToInt32(x["Id"])))["AccountType"]);" with join query .

Comment: Why First()?  Why enumerate with ForEach()? It seems like you want to do a GROUPBY and then get first item in Group.

Comment: this is the code written by another developer some years ago.i don't have any experience in linq so i am not sure what this code did. this was working in previous version but now i have changed some dll which don't have any dependency on this code and this is stop working.

Comment: i have also tried with the changed query to "SELECT rlat.* FROM tcRAPIDLoadAccountTypes rlat (NOLOCK) inner join MLSNAPS_XTCMConfig.dbo.tcRAPIDAccountTypes (nolock) rat on rlat.id = rat.Accounttypeid" to get the similar data but still having same issue.

Comment: I need you to use SQL Server Management Studio and get the table names, column names, and column types of the two tables.  We also need to verify the queries are returning data.  so put break point after two tables get filled then hover table name and select down arrow and click on Data Visualizer.

Comment: Details of tcRAPIDLoadAccountTypes -                                                                                             
 Column_name & type
Id(int)                   
AccountType(varchar)
AccountTypeDescription(varchar)
LOB (varchar)

Comment: details of tcRAPIDAccountTypes table -                                                                          
                                                                                                                                        
 Column_name Type
Id int
AccountTypeId int
Description varchar
IsActive bit
RuleJson nvarchar
EvaluationOrder int
RenderedClause nvarchar
CreatedById int
CreateDateTime datetime
LastModifiedById int
LastModifiedDateTime datetime
SqlStatement nvarchar

Comment: SELECT * FROM tcRAPIDLoadAccountTypes (NOLOCK) having data like :                                              
                                                                                                                                      
     Id AccountType AccountTypeDescription LOB
1 ABDNPROP NULL AP
2 ASR NULL CAS
4 BBUS NULL CAS
5 BRETL NULL CAS
6 BUSFLPOA NULL CAS
7 BVICMN NULL CAS
8 CORP NULL CAS
9 CPSACCT NULL CPS
10 DEFAULT NULL CODG

Comment: The query above should work without any exception.  I check everything completely.  It may not return any results, but that is a different issue.  I want to make sure there are no exception before proceeding any further.  So lets go slowly and get one thing working and then move on to next issue.  So get code above working without exceptions.

Comment: The query is joining Id from tcRAPIDLoadAccountTypes with AccountTypeId from tcRAPIDAccountTypes.  The data posted is showing ID is in a range from 1 to 10 while tcRAPIDAccountTypes is in a range from 15 to 46.  The two do not overlap so there will not be any join results.

Comment: Query returns expected result.ID range is different bcos i have select only 10 record .i can't not paste all record here due character length validation in this comment section .please see below result of same query :

Comment: Id AccountTypeId Description IsActive
66 1 NULL 1
64 2 NULL 1
30 3 NULL 1
18 4 NULL 1
19 5 NULL 1
57 6 NULL 1
35 8 NULL 1
17 9 NULL 1
59 10 NULL 1
52 11 NULL 1
51 12 NULL 1
23 13 NULL 1
28 14 NULL 1
15 15 NULL 1

Comment: only the problem with linq query. i have tried after getting same record (based on the ID )after place a join in query but again having same error. now i am not sure where is the problem.WHAT YOU THINK ?

Comment: It is possible the Ids in database are NULL.  So you may need to use int? (allows both integers and nulls).  So change following : cfg.Field<int?>("AccountTypeId") equals val.Field<int?>("Id")

Comment: Ids are not null Bcos this is primary key in table .